# Error creating and adding data to an SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to android and working on my first application creating a database. I want to add data to my database on clicking the save button. But I get an error.

My logcat says

`"12-09 12:15:41.204: ERROR/Database(565): Failure 1 (near "AUTO": syntax error) on 0x12f148 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE GoalTable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT, goals_title TEXT NOT NULL, start_date TEXT NOT NULL, target_date TEXT NOT NULL, reminder_date TEXT NOT NULL,);'.".`

Please help me find the error. Thanks.

Database.java

```
package com.firstproject.aditya;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Database {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "goals_title";
    public static final String KEY_STDATE = "start_date";
    public static final String KEY_TGDATE = "target_date";
    public static final String KEY_RDDATE = "reminder_date";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GoalInformation";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "GoalTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT, " + KEY_TITLE
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_STDATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_TGDATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_RDDATE
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase db,
                int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public Database(Context c) {
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public Database open() throws SQLException {
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String gTitle, String dateS, String dateT,
            String dateR) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_TITLE, gTitle);
        cv.put(KEY_STDATE, dateS);
        cv.put(KEY_TGDATE, dateT);
        cv.put(KEY_RDDATE, dateR);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public String getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_STDATE,
                KEY_TGDATE, KEY_RDDATE };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iTitle = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TITLE);
        int iStdate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_STDATE);
        int iTgdate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TGDATE);
        int iRddate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_RDDATE);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iTitle)
                    + " " + c.getString(iStdate) + " " + c.getString(iTgdate)
                    + " " + c.getString(iRddate) + "\n";
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: change INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT to                         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_ INCREMENT  and tell if the problem is solved :)

Comment: Not solved. Still persistent.

Comment: @AdityaSharma try typing AUTOINCREMENT as suggested in the answers and also put space at the end in the db.execSQL like this + " TEXT NOT NULL );"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be no space between `AUTO` and `INCREMENT`. It should be `AUTOINCREMENT`

Comment: This works..! Should have been more careful with spaces.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There should not be space between `AUTO INCREMENT`, It should be `AUTOINCREMENT`

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error in the onCreate statement. Look at the last part of the statement, bring the " symbol inside the ) i.e. + " TEXT NOT NULL");